# masonry loading as 1 column after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry for my portfolio items. When I go to the page directly, it loads the tiles in proper columns. However, my website is loaded using pjax and when I load the portfolio page, all of the porfolio items load in 1 single column, until I resize the window.

Its like masonry doesn't know the width of the client after an ajax request and then snaps out of it when the window is resized.

Anyone have experience with masonry that knows what I'm experiencing?

Comment: No online sandbox, no jsfiddle - hard to say where your error(s) could lie. For a start, Masonry needs the widths of elements to layout correctly, so it could be that you need to delay the Masonry callback.

Comment: I am experiencing it now, did you find any solution? apart from calling a reload?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your masonry call in a ajaxComplete so it fires after the ajax loads.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("Ajax finished"); //remove this if you want, useful for debugging
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#content').masonry({
       columnWidth: 260, //change this accordingly
       itemSelector: '.item'
      });
    });
});
```

Just wrestled with this issues myself.

better solution here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#admin_content').masonry({
       columnWidth: 260,
       itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
       isAnimated:true,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 500,
                    easing:'swing',
                    queue :false
               }
      });
    });
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#admin_content').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('#image_gallery');
$container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 230,
    itemSelector: '.brick'
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'post',
    success:function(response){
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        if(response.thumbs && response.thumbs.length > 0){
            $.each(response.thumbs, function(i, img){
                var eleHeight = (img.theight/img.twidth)*220;
                item += '<div class="brick" style="height:'+eleHeight+'px;width:220px"><a href="#">';
                item += '<img src="' + img.thumbUrl + '" /></a></div>';
    });
    }
    var $boxHtml = $(item);
        $container.append($boxHtml).masonry('appended', $boxHtml, true);
    }
});
});
```

Server side json output:

{
   thumbs:[{
        theight: 250
        thumbUrl: "/uploads/thumbs/image.jpg"
        twidth: 167.1875
     }]
}

Note: adjust columnWidth property to match width of brick div. (e.g. if brick div has padding left & right 5px then total width is 220+10 i.e. 230px as in above code)